# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to Rails and keep getting the error below. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please!

Error : undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Here is my memberships controller.

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

 def new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @membership = @project.memberships.build(project_id: @project.id, user_id: @user.id)
  redirect_to project_url(@membership.project_id)
 end

end
```

And Here is my form for membership.
It is nested underneath project routes.

```
<%= form_for([:project, @membership]) do |f|%>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label "Enter the email of the person you'd like to invite:" %>
   <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Save", :class=>"btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For your information, memberships table is a joining table between projects table and users table.

I can't figure out why I keep getting the error above. Maybe there is something I am missing. Help Please! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the 2 objects @user or @project cannot be found. Though the result becomes nil. You cannot call a method on a nil object. To know better where the faulty object is log the results.

```
Rails.logger.debug @user.inspect
Rails.logger.debug @project.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be `form_for [@project, @membership]` where `@project` is a Project instance, not `:project`.